# print list of set in string grid format

Tags: python, string, dictionary, grid, set

This is the txt file that I got:

```
......B..
.........
...A.....
.........
.......D.
.........
.C.......
.....E...
.........
```

from this text I made following elements for get closet alphabet from each dot in txtfile.

```
location_alpha ={(2, 3): 'A', (0, 6): 'B', (6, 1): 'C', (4, 7): 'D', (7, 5): 'E'}

location_allpoint = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)]
```

what I try to do is change all the dot in txt file to its closest Alphabet and print in string format:

```
   aaaabbBbb
   aaaaabbbb
   aaaAaabdd
   aaaaaaddd
   ccaaaddDd
   cccceeddd
   cCcceeedd
   ccceeEeee
   ccceeeeee
```

for do this what I got is nearest point for every item in txt.file:
what I tried to do is frist print lower case of each element in list to row*col string grid format like example up there, then change index of original alphabet to uppercase.

```
 for i in nearest_alphabet_from_point: 
      if len(i) ==2: # one that comes first lexicographically must be used in case ex){'A', 'C'} ==> 'A'

nearest_alphabet_from_point =[{'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'B'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'B'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'A', 'C'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'D', 'A'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'A', 'C'}, {'A'}, {'A'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'D'}, {'D'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'C'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}, {'E'}]
```

but I fail from frist step to print it in string grid format.

how can I do this?

Comment: Is this from https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/6?

Comment: @Alex no it's not, but it looks same except this part ==>Locations shown as . are equally far from two or more coordinates, and so they don't count as being closest to any, instead of this I need to choose closest alphabet lexicographically

Comment: for me only given information was just txt file

Comment: What does `nearest_alphabet_from_point` contain? Does it have the assigned char for each location in `location_allpoint` in that order?

Comment: @iamvegan Yes, it represent each char for each location in location_allpoint

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Just print the grid? or fill the dots?

Comment: @Alex make this    aaaabbBbb
   aaaaabbbb
   aaaAaabdd
   aaaaaaddd
   ccaaaddDd
   cccceeddd
   cCcceeedd
   ccceeEeee
   ccceeeeee  from it's original txt file both print string type grid and fill the dots

Comment: Can you re format your code with the correct indentation?

Comment: @Alex sorry for bad indentation I just corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to print the grid why don't you just do something like this?

```
N = len(nearest_alphabet_from_point)
W = 9
L = N//W
ind = 0
for i in range(L):
    for j in range(W):
        temp = list(nearest_alphabet_from_point[ind])
        ind += 1
        print(temp[0],end='')
    print('')
```

Output

```
AAAABBBBB
AAAAABBBB
AAAAAABDD
AAAAAADDD
CCAAADDDD
CCCCEEDDD
CCCCEEEDD
CCCEEEEEE
CCCEEEEEE
```

If you want to construct a `grid` of a `list` type, then you can do something like this:

```
N = len(nearest_alphabet_from_point)
W = 9
L = N//W
ind = 0
grid = []
for i in range(L):
    row = []
    for j in range(W):
        ch = list(nearest_alphabet_from_point[ind])[0]
        if (i,j) not in location_alpha:
            ch = ch.lower()
        row.append(ch)
        ind += 1
    grid.append(row)
```

Comment: I tried, but I want to change where dot is located to lowercase alphabet, and was not able to figure it out.... and didn't really understood how ==> print(temp[0], end='') this line works

Comment: Well if `(i,j)` is not in `location_alpha` it should be a dot right?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but may I ask the way to change it into return format not print?

Comment: think I figured it out just made another def for do it ty !

Comment: sorry again I made a other def, but it made some error, could you teach me way to change it in return format?

Comment: I know the way to make grid of a list, but struggle with make it into str type, is make new def for grid is a best option for do it?

Comment: oh it helped a lot thank you just change that into string by using join really appreciated!